# How to select data from a table where the table name has blank spaces in?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a situation, I have a mySql table named 'Master File' with contains 6000 records.

Howver I get an error `Warning:  mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource`

My code looks as below.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Master File";
$results = mysql_query($sql);


//Looping threw the Master File
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: For future reference, the error you received is a generic error meaning your query returned no results and therefore `$results` is null.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Master File`";
```

You need back ticks around fieldnames that have spaces.

Comment: This will also help when the table contains fields that are named after reserved words in MySQL like 'group' and 'sum'.  I have seen this happen to people before.  You can use the back ticks on the field names too.