# How to refer to a table name with a space in it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I import a csv file in phpmyadmin it automatically calls the table "table 1". Renaming the table is just one extra step I'd rather not take but the code below doesn't work because there's a space in the name. How can I refer to this table called "TABLE 1" when there's a space in the name?

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE 1")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select data from a table where the table name has blank spaces in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454950/how-to-select-data-from-a-table-where-the-table-name-has-blank-spaces-in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wrap it in backticks (`)

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1`");
```

Note: on a standard keyboard this is the to the left of the numeric "1" key

Comment: That gives me: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'or' (T_LOGICAL_OR) in ...public_html/mailer/testmail.php on line 11

Comment: Line 11 is: or die(mysql_error()); This error doesn't occur if the table is called TABLE1

Comment: So use your powers of deduction and try to isolate the syntax error, note I did terminate the line with `;` so perhaps you need to remove that.

Comment: No, this is the code copy and pasted: $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1`");
 or die(mysql_error());

Comment: so remove the "`;`" then from my answer

Comment: You copy and pasted that from your own site or from some sort of tutorial somewhere? Because if it's from a tutorial, it's garbage. mysql_* functions are deprecated and should not be used for any new projects.

Comment: Now I get: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''TABLE 1'' at line 1

Comment: Did you leave out the backticks?

Comment: This is it:  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'TABLE 1'") 
 or die(mysql_error());

Comment: you put in single quotes and not backticks like I posted? Note backticks are shared with the tilde key `~`

Comment: You can keep using single quotes if you'd like to keep getting MySQL syntax errors.

Comment: and there was much rejoicing